# Date formate of Arabic date

Tags: php, date, arabic

I am using this code to get Arabic Date.

```
    $DateTime          = new DateTime();

    $IntlDateFormatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'en_US@calendar=islamic-civil',
    IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM,
    IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM,
    'Europe/London',
    IntlDateFormatter::TRADITIONAL );

echo $IntlDateFormatter->format( $DateTime );
```

I am getting result `Muh. 4, 1445 AH, 4:01:56 PM`. But I need date `4 Muharram 1445`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this should work:

```php
<?php
$DateTime = new DateTime();

$IntlDateFormatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'en_US@calendar=islamic-civil',
    IntlDateFormatter::NONE, // No date format, as we'll specify the pattern manually
    IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM, // Use default time format
    'Europe/London',
    IntlDateFormatter::TRADITIONAL
);

// Set the custom pattern for the date
$pattern = "d MMMM y";
$IntlDateFormatter->setPattern($pattern);

echo $IntlDateFormatter->format($DateTime);
```

the `$pattern = "d MMMM y";` is the cause

Comment: Thanks @Hind Sagar Biswas. Your solution is working. Thanks.